# Loguearse sin contraseña y sin tabla usuarios

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, login

Se que parece contradictorio, pero no puedo hacer funcionar esto.
Para estar en contexto, estoy usando Laravel 5.7 y lo que quiero hacer es:
Desde un sistema php legacy necesitaría loguearme al sistema nuevo con Laravel.
En realidad no habría un "logueo", el sistema legacy enviaría un link con un token (un objeto hasheado) y desde laravel deshashearía ese objeto e inicializaría el Auth y la Sesión.

El problema es que no se como inicializar/instanciar el Auth y la Sesión, ya que si voy a /home me redireccionar al login.

Gracias!!

Comment: debes revisar las rutas en la web.php, a veces ocurre errores de redireccionamiento y debes estar pendiente de eso.

Comment: Hola Ramon, gracias por contestar. No era un tema de rutas. Era un tema de como inicializar la session y Auth.